# Scrollview -> Relativelayout -> TabLayout don't scroll whole layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, tabs, scrollview

I am Trying to scroll whole layout but I can't, only tablayout scroll and relative layout above the tablayout they can't scroll, how to fix it, I am trying to make like instagram profile or account fragment page... help to fix it... thanks in advance and I am using under tablayout framelayout not a viewpager and attach with framelayout fragment the 1st tab I can click then that fragment use the scroll, linear and the recyclerview that fragment call then whole layout scroll, but another second tab I can click then that fragment use the linear and gridview only and that fragment call then half layout scroll, where I am wrong please tell me...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/imglayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/cvprofile"
                    android:layout_width="86dp"
                    android:layout_height="86dp"
                    app:civ_border_color="#a4a4a4"
                    app:civ_border_width="0.5dp"
                    android:layout_margin="12dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/img" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/digitlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imglayout"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/post"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="100"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/followers"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="100"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/following"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="43"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/textlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imglayout"
                android:layout_below="@id/digitlayout"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/posts"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="posts"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/followerss"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="follwers"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/followings"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="follwers"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>  
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvedit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/edit_profile"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_textview"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imglayout"
                android:layout_below="@id/textlayout"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
           <View
                android:id="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_below="@id/imglayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:background="#b6b6b6" />
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_below="@id/view1"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed">
                   <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:icon="@drawable/frame1"/>
                    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:icon="@drawable/frame1" />
                    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:icon="@drawable/frame1" />
                    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:icon="@drawable/frame1" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
            <View
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:background="#b6b6b6" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/framelayout"
                android:layout_below="@id/view2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: i think your all data is set on scrollview so it's not scroll. if your data go outside of device screen then it's scroll.

Comment: data set on relativelayout ....and already data go to outside of screen but cant scrollable ...only down parts scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing ScrollView to NestedScrollView

```
android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
```

Comment: not working bro....my layout with scrolllayout can scroll half but using nestedscrollview not scroll even half...n thanx for trying to help me bro

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a LinearLayout inside your ScrollView(ScrollView --> LiearLayout-->RelativeLayout--> ...). Or just add android:fillViewport="true" to your Scrollview.

Comment: i can try already but cant, another solution ?? programatically or xml through anything...

Answer (score 0):

Bro, I just copied your code to m xml and there is no problem with the scrolling...if you still have a problem then just add a relative layout before scrollview ....like this

RelativeLAyout>ScrollView>RelativeLayout

Comment: not working bro ... coz i m using onTabClick call the fragment which is include the linearlayout-> gridview...so cant scrolling whole layout...n thanx for try to help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imglayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/cvprofile"
            android:layout_width="86dp"
            android:layout_height="86dp"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img"
            app:civ_border_color="#a4a4a4"
            app:civ_border_width="0.5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/digitlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imglayout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="100"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/followers"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="100"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/following"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="43"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/digitlayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imglayout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/posts"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="posts"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/followerss"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="follwers"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/followings"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="follwers"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvedit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textlayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imglayout"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_textview"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/edit_profile"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/imglayout"
        android:background="#b6b6b6" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/view1"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:icon="@drawable/frame1" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:icon="@drawable/frame1" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:icon="@drawable/frame1" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:icon="@drawable/frame1" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout"
        android:background="#b6b6b6" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/view2"></FrameLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: not working bro...coz attached fragment used gridview